# Failing to install Boost in Python - pyconfig.h not found

Tags: python-3.x, boost, dlib

I'm following along this [tutorial](https://gist.github.com/ageitgey/629d75c1baac34dfa5ca2a1928a7aeaf) on how to make simple face recognition using Python. The tutorial is dependent on the dlib library which I'm trying to install. However, the dlib library has a dependency on the Boost library and yields this error:

```
-- Found PythonLibs: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/libpython3.6.dylib (found suitable version "3.6.0", minimum required is "3.4")
--  *****************************************************************************************************
--  To compile Boost.Python yourself download boost from boost.org and then go into the boost root folder
--  and run these commands:
--     ./bootstrap.sh --with-libraries=python
--     ./b2
--     sudo ./b2 install
```

When I run `./bootstrap.sh --with-libraries=python` from the Boost download folder I get the following error:

```
darwin.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/python/build/darwin-4.2.1/release/threading-multi/numeric.o
In file included from libs/python/src/numeric.cpp:6:
In file included from ./boost/python/numeric.hpp:8:
In file included from ./boost/python/detail/prefix.hpp:13:
./boost/python/detail/wrap_python.hpp:50:11: fatal error: 'pyconfig.h' file not found
# include <pyconfig.h>
          ^
1 error generated.

    "g++"  -ftemplate-depth-128 -O3 -Wall -dynamic -gdwarf-2 -fexceptions -Wno-inline -fPIC -arch x86_64  -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1 -DBOOST_PYTHON_SOURCE -DNDEBUG  -I"." -I"/Users/mikkeld/anaconda/include/python3.5" -c -o "bin.v2/libs/python/build/darwin-4.2.1/release/threading-multi/numeric.o" "libs/python/src/numeric.cpp"
```

I'm a bit lost here and have tried looking around without luck. Can anyone spot what the issue is?

Comment: Try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19810940/ubuntu-linking-boost-python-fatal-error-pyconfig-cannot-be-found

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for this solution and one above I found my include link of python via:
Open your terminal and run:
python --version

Replace the 3.7 for your current Python version and run:

```
python3.7-config --includes --libs
```

link:

```
/Users/<username>/.pyenv/versions/3.6.7/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/include/python3.6m
```

and replaced the link which I found in `C_INCLUDE_PATH` below

Edit `/etc/profile`, and append following to the file, you should modify the path for specifying your python header

```
C_INCLUDE_PATH=$C_INCLUDE_PATH:/usr/local/include/python3.6m
export C_INCLUDE_PATH
CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=$CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH:/usr/local/include/python3.6m
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH
Source /etc/profile
```

Compile again
it compiles boost now!

Comment: Its a thank you note + modified answer using above two answers

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer for those who use Anaconda.

Open your terminal and run:
`python --version`

Replace the `3.7` for your current Python version and run:
`python3.7-config --includes --libs`

> -I/home/victor/anaconda3/include/python3.7m -I/home/victor/anaconda3/include/python3.7m
>   -lpython3.7m -lpthread -ldl  -lutil -lrt -lm

Now, get the first item returned and add the following line on your `~/.bashrc`:

```
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH="$CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH:/home/victor/anaconda3/include/python3.7m"
```

Source your new bashrc file
`source ~/.bashrc_profile`

Comment: I had the same error, I followed these directions on MacOS and it appeared to have corrected my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I also met this problem when I compile boost, following is my solution.

1. Install python
2. Edit /etc/profile, and append following to the file, you should modify the path for specifying your python header

   C_INCLUDE_PATH=$C_INCLUDE_PATH:/usr/local/include/python3.6m

   export C_INCLUDE_PATH

   CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=$CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH:/usr/local/include/python3.6m

   export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH
3. Source /etc/profile
4. Compile again

It works for me, hope you so.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a technique that worked for me under boost 1.72 and python 3.7 from anaconda on Ubuntu 18.04.

- Make sure your anaconda environment is active (the correct python in path)
- In your boost source tree edit the file `tools/build/src/tools/python.jam`
- Look for line 547 `includes ?= $(prefix)/include/python$(version) ;`
- Replace with  `includes ?= $(prefix)/include/python$(version)m ;`
- `./bootstrap.sh` and  `./b2 install` as usual