# How to fix : pyconfig.h not found with Anaconda

Tags: python, c++, binding

I am setting up boost-python for the python bindings of a library. Previously, boost was installed but linked against python2.7. After some tribulations, everything from the previous boost install is gone and I am trying to install a fresh boost.

I am using Linux Mint for the record, and Anaconda with python 3.6.8.
It works correctly in the CLI : python --version gives 3.6.8

I then begin to follow the instructions for building boost : https://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_69_0.html

What I got from other threads is to do this :

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev
```

I am not sure I am supposed to since I have anaconda3 but anyway, I did it.

```
./bootstrap.sh
```

here the file project-config.jam is created and the line about python says :

```
using python : 3.6 : /home/myUser/anaconda3 ;
```

I then proceed to build with b2 :

```
sudo ./b2 --with-python -j8 install
```

the installation fails with literally a wall of text full of these :

```
./boost/python/detail/wrap_python.hpp:50:11: fatal error: 
pyconfig.h: No such file or directory
# include <pyconfig.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

When I search inside ~/anaconda3/include/python3.6m the file pyconfig.h sits there as expected

Is there additional information I should give to b2 or bootstrap ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I face the same problem for installing boost 1.70 and Anaconda3 with python Anaconda with python 3.7.1. I found an answer based on this question.
[Ubuntu - Linking boost.python - Fatal error: pyconfig cannot be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19810940/ubuntu-linking-boost-python-fatal-error-pyconfig-cannot-be-found)

By the way to solve this problem first you should find the "pyconfig.h" file in the installation directory of Anaconda. For me it's in "~/anaconda3/include/python3.7m". Then export this address or just add this address to the .bashrc file.

```
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH="$CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH:path/to/your/Anaconda3/include/python3.7m"
```

Put the address to Anaconda in your pc instead of path/to/your/Anaconda3. Remember to restart the terminal after this. Then again just run "./b2" in the boost folder. It should compile the rest.